# What is the Relationship between Instagram users and user followers

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I'm building a blog project, which each user can follow other users. I'm still figuring out the design and creating the diagrams first. I know that the relationship between users and followers is many to many. Is this the correct approach for the ER design of the relationship?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between Instagram user and follower is many to many because:

One user can have multiple followers.
One follower can have multiple "followed users".

Useful:  Always name the entities (classes) as singular e.g. User & Follower

Comment: is the diagram correct?

Comment: Not Exactly. There should be one line between two entities for clear representation of a relationship. You can make three classes for many-to-many relationship. The third table will be "user_follower" with user_id and follower_id as the foreign keys. 

For further clarification, please refer to this
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/data-modeling/what-is-entity-relationship-diagram/